# Assetic failed in dev environment

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm trying to run `assetic:dump` from Symfony2 shell but it stops at some point and hangs there, this is the message I get:

> [error] The source file
>   "/var/www/html/app/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
>   does not exist.

I used MopaBootstrapBundle in the past but I non longer needed so I remove it and after that I run all this commands:

```
Symfony > cache:clear
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
Symfony > cache:warmup
Warming up the cache for the dev environment with debug true
Symfony > assetic:dump --watch
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is on.

[error] The source file "/var/www/html/app/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" does not exist.
```

Any advice? What I'm doing wrong?

**Adding assetic config at `config.yml`**

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        
      - PlantillaBundle
      - ComunBundle
      - UsuarioBundle
    java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        cssembed:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed.jar
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar
    assets:
        fonts_glyphicons_eot:
            inputs:
               - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
        fonts_glyphicons_svg:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
        fonts_glyphicons_ttf:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
        fonts_glyphicons_woff:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
```

Comment: Somewhere in your templates, you have referenced that glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot file, but the reference is invalid. Could you please post the part of your template with that reference? And, what's the actual path to that file?

Comment: @lxg that was the problem I forgot totally to delete the `assets` at `config.yml` now I deleted and the command runs well but console get stuck, maybe a Symfony2 bug or something else, please answer yhe question to give your points and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your templates, you have referenced that `glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` file, but the reference is invalid.

To get a clue of where to look, a simple *grep* will help:

```
grep -r glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot src/ app/config vendor/
```